# Is in C++ possible create generic function like read<type>()?

Tags: c++, templates

I have one question (Which is in title too): Is in C++ possible create generic function like `read<type>()`?

I already tried it by:

```
template <typename T>
T read() {
    T res;

    if (typeid(T) == typeid(int))
    {
        // some stuff
    }
    else if (/*some other type check*/) {} // etc.
}
```

And when i tried to compile this, it threw: `Invalid conversion from **** to ****`. I know why it is throwing exception like this, but is it possible to do that in C++?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for explaining what the `read` function is supposed to do!

Comment: Your issue is probably in the parts of code which you *didn't* post. Remember that *all* branches of the ifs will be compiled for all types, and only optimised out later. You probably want to define multiple unique functions for each type. So you would have `template<> double read<double>(){...}` and so on.

Comment: Ahh... sorry. It is doing some things which are concrete for the type. Such as string.reserve(), or vector<type> method push_back(), etc. so the compiler can't compile it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve something like this. The easiest way is probably to use an explicit specialization:

```
template <typename T>
T read() {
    T res;

    // etc.
}

template <>
int read<int>() {
    int res;

    // your special int code
}
```

Depending on what you want to do you may need to use [tag dispatch](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching) instead.

Note that you should only do this if you can come up with reasonable behavior for the default "unknown T" case. If you only ever want the user to pick one if your predefined special values of `T` then you should just have separate functions and not use templates here.

Answer (score 2):

With templates is possible to do metaprogramming and abstract the actual type to a generic type T, is also possible to

- overload a template so the type deduction system will pick the overloaded version instead of the "generic" version
- use the SFINAE technique to pick a given implementation when some conditions are verified
- [assertions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/)
- in C++11 environments is also possible to use [type_traits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/)

remember that templates are here to leverage you from writing the same implementation for a given function for every type that you use, it's a compile-time feature, after the compilation templates are translated into functions.
If you need to specify a given behaviour based on the type that you got in input, you maybe interested in SFINAE, type_traits, or other similar solution.

You can also template "quantities", numbers, for example you can template an `int`.

Beware of the fact that templates do not impose a particular "filter" on the type like a check of the signature that a function performs, you can literally throw any type or class to a template, this is one drawback of the templates that you need to handle almost everytime you are using a template.

Comment: Overloading is not helpful here because the function doesn't have arguments. This is a good overview of how to make decisions at compile time but I don't think it works for the OP's specific scenario.

Comment: @BillyONeal I was starting from the assumption that you can't really make a 100% generic template in C++, at some point you have to make decisions most of the time. Even in the classic Fibonacci example you have at least 1 overloaded template.

Comment: Erm, there are plenty of truly generic templates in C++. Consider `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` or `std::list` or `std::map` etc. Of course metaprogramming requires specializations but not everyone needs to be doing metaprogramming.